# Solaris and Preprocessor Macros

Tags: macros, preprocessor, solaris

Would someone post the results of `cpp -dM < /dev/null` from a Solaris 10 or above system?

I'm having trouble locating what preprocessor macros are typically defined. Solaris documentation does not discuss it in detail [[1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/cpp-1/index.html)], [[2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-6223/chp-prog-5/index.html)], and Google is not being very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using the Solaris Studio compilers, the pre-defined list is under the -D flag in [the cc man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24457_01/html/E22003/cc.1.html).

Comment: While looking for Solaris macros, I stumbled upon this: [Sun Studio 12: C User's Guide  > Chapter 2 C-Compiler Information Specific to Sun’s Implementation  > 2.9 Predefined Names](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5265/bjada/index.html) which isn't exactly what OP asked, but it might be useful to someone else who stumbles upon this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solaris 11.1

```
#define __DBL_MIN_EXP__ (-1021)
#define __FLT_MIN__ 1.17549435e-38F
#define __CHAR_BIT__ 8
#define __WCHAR_MAX__ 2147483647
#define __DBL_DENORM_MIN__ 4.9406564584124654e-324
#define __FLT_EVAL_METHOD__ 0
#define __DBL_MIN_10_EXP__ (-307)
#define __FINITE_MATH_ONLY__ 0
#define __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ 3
#define sparc 1
#define __SHRT_MAX__ 32767
#define __LDBL_MAX__ 1.18973149535723176508575932662800702e+4932L
#define __unix 1
#define __LDBL_MAX_EXP__ 16384
#define __SCHAR_MAX__ 127
#define __USER_LABEL_PREFIX__ 
#define __STDC_HOSTED__ 1
#define __LDBL_HAS_INFINITY__ 1
#define __DBL_DIG__ 15
#define __FLT_EPSILON__ 1.19209290e-7F
#define __LDBL_MIN__ 3.36210314311209350626267781732175260e-4932L
#define __unix__ 1
#define __DECIMAL_DIG__ 36
#define __LDBL_HAS_QUIET_NAN__ 1
#define __GNUC__ 3
#define __DBL_MAX__ 1.7976931348623157e+308
#define __DBL_HAS_INFINITY__ 1
#define __SVR4 1
#define __DBL_MAX_EXP__ 1024
#define __LONG_LONG_MAX__ 9223372036854775807LL
#define __sparc__ 1
#define __GXX_ABI_VERSION 1002
#define __FLT_MIN_EXP__ (-125)
#define __DBL_MIN__ 2.2250738585072014e-308
#define __DBL_HAS_QUIET_NAN__ 1
#define __sun 1
#define __REGISTER_PREFIX__ 
#define __NO_INLINE__ 1
#define __FLT_MANT_DIG__ 24
#define __VERSION__ "3.4.3 (csl-sol210-3_4-20050802)"
#define __sparc 1
#define sun 1
#define unix 1
#define __SIZE_TYPE__ unsigned int
#define __ELF__ 1
#define __FLT_RADIX__ 2
#define __LDBL_EPSILON__ 1.92592994438723585305597794258492732e-34L
#define __FLT_HAS_QUIET_NAN__ 1
#define __FLT_MAX_10_EXP__ 38
#define __LONG_MAX__ 2147483647L
#define __FLT_HAS_INFINITY__ 1
#define __PRAGMA_REDEFINE_EXTNAME 1
#define __LDBL_MANT_DIG__ 113
#define __WCHAR_TYPE__ long int
#define __FLT_DIG__ 6
#define __INT_MAX__ 2147483647
#define __FLT_MAX_EXP__ 128
#define __DBL_MANT_DIG__ 53
#define __WINT_TYPE__ long int
#define __LDBL_MIN_EXP__ (-16381)
#define __LDBL_MAX_10_EXP__ 4932
#define __DBL_EPSILON__ 2.2204460492503131e-16
#define __sun__ 1
#define __svr4__ 1
#define __FLT_DENORM_MIN__ 1.40129846e-45F
#define __FLT_MAX__ 3.40282347e+38F
#define __FLT_MIN_10_EXP__ (-37)
#define __GNUC_MINOR__ 4
#define __DBL_MAX_10_EXP__ 308
#define __LDBL_DENORM_MIN__ 6.47517511943802511092443895822764655e-4966L
#define __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ int
#define __LDBL_MIN_10_EXP__ (-4931)
#define __LDBL_DIG__ 33
```

Comment: That's interesting. Neither Solaris nor its version show up in the dump.

Comment: Solaris is traditionally detected with `#if defined(__sun) && defined(__SVR4)`, though checking for `__SVR4` is only interesting now if you need to make sure you're not running on a 20-year old SunOS 4.   The Solaris Studio compilers additionally define an OS version specific macro, such as `__SunOS_5_11` but that's a -D flag that cc & CC pass to the preprocessor, not a cpp-builtin value.

Comment: Is there no [__LP64__](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) defined?  How can I determine if the host is a 32b or 64b Solaris host?

Comment: The system headers will define `_ILP32` or `_LP64` depending on if you pass -m32 or -m64 (or similar flags) to the compiler.  It's not a cpp builtin, but something the headers set up.

Comment: @jim - please have a look at [How to print preprocessor macros under Sun Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37715467) when you have a moment.

Answer (score 2):

@jens:

Sparc systems from Solaris 10 onwards are always 64bit. X64 systems came in with Solaris 10, though you could still boot a 32bit x86 kernel.

```
$ isainfo
amd64 i386
$ isainfo -b
64
$ isainfo -v
    64-bit amd64 applications
        avx xsave pclmulqdq aes sse4.2 sse4.1 ssse3 popcnt tscp ahf cx16 sse3 
        sse2 sse fxsr mmx cmov amd_sysc cx8 tsc fpu efs f16c rdrand 
    32-bit i386 applications
        avx xsave pclmulqdq aes sse4.2 sse4.1 ssse3 popcnt tscp ahf cx16 sse3 
        sse2 sse fxsr mmx cmov sep cx8 tsc fpu efs f16c rdrand
```

`/usr/bin/isainfo` is your friend, from the command line.

From a programmatic point of view, examine the #defines in `<sys/feature_tests.h>`. You'll notice `_LP64` ...

Comment: Please have a look at [How to print preprocessor macros under Sun Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37715467) when you have a moment.